# Apollo Client query ​Missing field __typename

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo-client, apollo-link-rest

I am trying to use `apollo-link-rest` with the Star Wars API and I am getting some errors.

```
import { InMemoryCache } from "apollo-cache-inmemory";
import { ApolloClient } from "apollo-client";
import { RestLink } from "apollo-link-rest";
import gql from "graphql-tag";

// node environment?
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
global.fetch = fetch;
global.Headers = fetch.Headers;

const restLink = new RestLink({
  endpoints: { swapi: "https://swapi.co/api/" }
});

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: restLink,
  cache: new InMemoryCache()
});

const query = gql`
  query people {
    search
      @rest(type: "Search", path: "people/?search=skywalker", endpoint: swapi) {
      count
      results {
        name
      }
    }
  }
`;

client
  .query({ query })
  .then(response => console.log(JSON.stringify(response)))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Errors:

```
​​​Missing field __typename in {​​​
​​​  "name": "Luke Skywalker"​​​
​​​}​​​
​​​​​​
​​​Missing field __typename in {​​​
​​​  "name": "Anakin Skywalker"​​​
​​​}​​​
​​​​​​
​​​Missing field __typename in {​​​
​​​  "name": "Shmi Skywalker"​​​
​​​}​​​
```

I know I can change set this `InMemoryCache({ addTypename: false })` to remove the errors, but I don't know what the impact on caching will be if I set `addTypename` to `false`.

Can someone point me in the right direction on this?

Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out what the docs have to say about [typename patching](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/link/links/rest.html#options.typePatcher).

Your `@rest` directive tells the client what typename to expect for the `search` field, but doesn't say anything about any types inside the field's selection set. There's two ways to fix that. You can use a `@type` directive:

```
query people {
  search @rest(type: "Search", path: "people/?search=skywalker", endpoint: swapi) {
    count
    results @type(name: "Person") {
      name
    }
  }
}
```

Or configure a `typePatcher`. Something like:

```
const restLink = new RestLink({
  uri: 'https://swapi.co/api/',
  typePatcher: {
    Search: (data, outerType, patchDeeper) => {
      if (data.results != null) {
        data.results = data.results.map(person => {
          return {__typename: "Person", ...person }
        });
      }
      return data
    },
  },
})
```

Answer (score 0):

More generic answer:

to avoid the `missing __typename` error ensure any arrays in your GQL model has a corresponding field `__typename` for EACH object in the array.